# What is the difference between const_iterator and non-const iterator in the C++ STL?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, constants

What is the difference between a `const_iterator` and an `iterator` and where would you use one over the other?

Comment: Well, the name const_iterator sounds like the iterator is const, while the thing this iterator points to is the actual const.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

`const_iterator`s don't allow you to change the values that they point to, regular `iterator`s do.

As with all things in C++, always prefer `const`, unless there's a good reason to use regular iterators (i.e. you want to use the fact that they're not `const` to change the pointed-to value).

Comment: In a perfect world that would be the case.  But with C++ const is only as good as the person who wrote the code :(

Comment: mutable exists for a very good reason. It is rarely used, and looking at Google Code Search, there appears to be fair percentage of valid uses. The keyword is a very powerful optimization tool, and it's not like removing it would improve const-correctness(*coughpointerscoughandcoughreferencescough*)

Comment: More like a powerful hack.  Of all the instances I have ever seen of the use of the 'mutable' keyword, all but one was an accurate indicator that the code was poorly written and mutable was needed as a hack to get around the defects.

Comment: It does have legitimate uses, like caching the results of a long calculation within a const class. On the other hand, that's pretty much the only time I've used a mutable in nearly twenty years of C++ development.

Comment: A generic example for using const_iterator would be when the iterator is an rvalue

Comment: mutexes are the most common use for `mutable` I've seen.  Say you have a `const` object you want to read from in a multi-threaded scenario where a different thread may change the object via a non-const method. In this case even to read the const object you have to lock the `mutex` which is a non-const method.  Declaring the `mutex` as `mutable` is the simplest solution.

Comment: @schrödinbug Why would one thread change a `const` object? Isn't that just another example of poor design? No offense, I'm genuinely asking.

Comment: If you have an object that is shared between two or more threads. One thread is the writer and the others just read the value (via getter that locks the mutex) to make their local copy. Depending on where the object is instantiated, all the reader threads may just have const &s to the object. However given that shared state is the root of all multi-threaded evil, your statement may be correct.

Answer (score 51):

They should pretty much be self-explanatory. If iterator points to an element of type T, then const_iterator points to an element of type 'const T'.

It's basically equivalent to the pointer types:

```
T* // A non-const iterator to a non-const element. Corresponds to std::vector<T>::iterator
T* const // A const iterator to a non-const element. Corresponds to const std::vector<T>::iterator
const T* // A non-const iterator to a const element. Corresponds to std::vector<T>::const_iterator
```

A const iterator always points to the same element, so the iterator *itself* is const. But the element it points to does not have to be const, so the element it points to can be changed.
A const_iterator is an iterator that points to a const element, so while the iterator itself can be updated (incremented or decremented, for example), the element it points to can not be changed.

Comment: "A const iterator always points to the same element,"  This is incorrect.

Comment: How so? Note the missing underscore. I'm contrasting a variable of type const std::vector<T>::iterator with std::vector<T>::const_iterator.
In the former case, the iterator itself is const, so it can't be modified, but the element it references can be modified freely.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yes I missed the missing underscore.

Comment: @JohnDibling Upvoted for explaining the subtlety between `const iterater` and `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 9):

**Minimal runnable examples**

Non-const iterators allow you to modify what they point to:

```
std::vector<int> v{0};
std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
*it = 1;
assert(v[0] == 1);
```

Const iterators don't:

```
const std::vector<int> v{0};
std::vector<int>::const_iterator cit = v.begin();
// Compile time error: cannot modify container with const_iterator.
//*cit = 1;
```

As shown above, `v.begin()` is `const` overloaded, and returns either `iterator` or `const_iterator` depending on the const-ness of the container variable:

- [How does begin() know which return type to return (const or non-const)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646998/how-does-begin-know-which-return-type-to-return-const-or-non-const)
- [how does overloading of const and non-const functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103543/how-does-overloading-of-const-and-non-const-functions-work)

A common case where `const_iterator` pops up is when `this` is used inside a `const` method:

```
class C {
    public:
        std::vector<int> v;
        void f() const {
            std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = this->v.begin();
        }
        void g(std::vector<int>::const_iterator& it) {}
};
```

`const` makes `this` const, which makes `this->v` const.

You can usually forget about it with `auto`, but if you starting passing those iterators around, you will need to think about them for the method signatures.

Much like const and non-const, you can convert easily from non-const to const, but not the other way around:

```
std::vector<int> v{0};
std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();

// non-const to const.
std::vector<int>::const_iterator cit = it;

// Compile time error: cannot modify container with const_iterator.
//*cit = 1;

// Compile time error: no conversion from const to no-const.
//it = ci1;
```

Which one to use: analogous to `const int` vs `int`: prefer const iterators whenever you can use them (when you don't need to modify the container with them), to better document your intention of reading without modifying.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunaty, a lot of the methods for the STL containers takes **iterators** instead of **const_iterators** as parameters. So if you have a **const_iterator**, you can't say "insert an element before the element that this iterator points to" (saying such a thing is not conceptually a const violation, in my opinion). If you want do that anyway, you have to convert it to a non-const iterator using **std::advance()** or **boost::next()**. Eg. **boost::next(container.begin(), std::distance(container.begin(), the_const_iterator_we_want_to_unconst))**. If **container** is a **std::list**, then the running time for that call will be **O(n)**.

So the universal rule to add const wherever it is "logical" to do so, is less universal when it comes to STL containers.

However, boost containers take const_iterators (eg. boost::unordered_map::erase()). So when you use boost containers you can be "const agressive". By the way, do anyone know if or when the STL containers will be fixed?

Comment: It may be a matter of opinion. In the case of `vector` and `deque`, inserting one element invalidates all existing iterators, which isn't very `const`. But I do see your point. Such operations are protected by container `const`-ness, not the iterators. And I do wonder why there isn't a const-to-nonconst iterator conversion function in the standard container interface.

Comment: You are correct Potatoswatter, I am to categorical, it is a matter of opinion for the random access containers and **container.begin() + (the_const_iterator_we_want_to_unconst – container.begin())** is **O(1)** anyway. I also wonder why there is no conversion function for the non-random access containers, but maybe there is a good reason? Do you know if there is some reason that the functions for the non-random access containers do not take **const_iterators**?

Comment: "saying such a thing is not conceptually a const violation, in my opinion" - this is a very interesting comment, I have the following thoughts on the topic.  With simple pointers, one can say `int const * foo;` `int * const foo;` and `int const * const foo;`all three are valid and useful, each in their own way.  `std::vector<int> const bar` should be the same as the second one, but it is unfortunately often treated like the third.  The root cause of the problem is that we can't say `std::vector<int const> bar;` when means there's no way to get the same effect as `int const *foo;` in a vector.

Answer (score 7):

Use **const_iterator** whenever you can, use **iterator** when you have no other choice.

Answer (score 0):

(as others have said) const_iterator doesn't allow you modify the elements to which it points, this is useful inside of const class methods.  It also allows you to express your intent.

Answer (score 0):

ok Let me explain it with very simple example first without using constant iterator
consider we have collection of random integers collection "randomData"

```
    for(vector<int>::iterator i = randomData.begin() ; i != randomData.end() ; ++i)*i = 0;
for(vector<int>::const_iterator i = randomData.begin() ; i!= randomData.end() ; ++i)cout << *i;
```

As can be seen for writing/editing data inside collection normal iterator is used but for reading purpose constant iterator has been used . If you try using constant iterator in first for loop you will get error . As a thumb rule use constant iterator to read data inside collection .