# How does overloading of const and non-const functions work?

Tags: c++, function, stl, constants, overloading

The `STL` is full of definitions like this:

```
iterator begin ();
const_iterator begin () const;
```

As return value does not participate in overloading resolution, the only difference here is the function being `const`. Is this part of the overloading mechanism? What is the compiler's algorithm for resolving a line like:

```
vector<int>::const_iterator it = myvector.begin();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the example you gave:

```
vector<int>::const_iterator it = myvector.begin();
```

if `myvector` isn't const the non-const version of `begin()` will be called and you will be relying on an implicit conversion from iterator to const_iterator.

Answer (score 12):

The compiler's "algorithm" is like this:
Every member function of class X has an implicit argument of type X& (I know, most think it's X*, but the standard states, that for purposes of Overload Resolution we assume it to be a reference). For const functions, the type of the argument is const X&. Thus the algorithm, if a member function is called the two versions, const and non-const, are both viable candidates, and the best match is selected just as in other cases of overload resolution. No magic :)

Comment: thanks, this is useful, however my problem was the (wrong) assumption that the const variant is called because of the type of the variable it is assigned to. @awoodland explained this

Comment: Why reference and not pointer and that too only for overload resolution, any non-obvious reason for it ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the `const` modifier affects overloading. If `myvector` is `const` at that point `const` version will be called:

```
void stuff( const vector<int>& myvector )
{
    vector<int>::const_iterator it = myvector.begin(); //const version will be called
}

vector<int> myvector;    
vector<int>::const_iterator it = myvector.begin(); //non-const version will be called
```

Answer (score 3):

From C++ standard (§13.3.1 Candidate functions and argument lists):

`For non-static member functions, the type of the implicit object parameter is “reference to cv X” where X is the class of which the function is a member and cv is the cv-qualification on the member function declaration. [Example: for a const member function of class X, the extra parameter is assumed to have type “reference to const X”. ]`

So, in your case, if `myvector` object is `const` compiler will pick version of `begin` which has implicit object parameter of type `reference to const vector` which is const version of `begin`.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth mentioning that c++ **allows const methods/functions overloading** (e.g. foo() const), but **not const arguments** overloading (e.g. bar(int a) and bar(const int a)).

Comment: you can overload the 2nd if they are references

Answer (score 2):

**The compiler determines if the object variable is const or not at compile time**

It then picks the corresponding overload, and whatever return type it has.

```
class C {
    public:
        int f() { return 1; }
        float f() const { return 1.5; }
};

// Non const.
C c;
assert(c.f() == 1);

// Convert variable const at compile time.
assert(const_cast<const C&>(c).f() == 1.5);

// Same as above but with an explicit reference.
const C& d = c;
assert(d.f() == 1.5);

// Analogous but with a new const object from the start.
const C e;
assert(d.f() == 1.5);
```