# How does begin() know which return type to return (const or non-const)?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, std

This works perfectly :

```
list<int> l;
list<int>::const_iterator it;
it = l.begin();
list<int>::iterator it2;
it2 = l.begin();
```

What I don't get is how the `list` "knows" that it must return the `iterator begin()` version or the `const_iterator begin() const` one.

I'm trying to implement iterators for my container (a trie) and I'm running into this problem. Isn't C++ supposed not to handle differentiation by return type (except when using weird tricks)?

Here is some code and the compiler error I get :

My `Trie<T>` is a templated trie that can contain any type. I have a `Trie<int>::iter` non-const iterator and a `Trie<int>::const_iter` const iterator. `iter begin()` and `const_iter begin() const` are declared (and defined) in the Trie class.

```
Trie<int> t;
Trie<int>::const_iter it;
it = t.begin();
```

Error :

```
../test/trie.cpp:181: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'it = Trie<T>::begin() [with T = int]()'
[..path..]/Trie.h:230: note: candidates are: Trie<int>::const_trie_iterator& Trie<int>::const_trie_iterator::operator=(const Trie<int>::const_trie_iterator&)
```

So, I believe the non-const version of `begin` is not used.

I contemplated creating an `operator=(const Trie<T>::const_trie_iterator&)` method for the non-const iterator but I don't see that in the `STD` lib and I would have to const_cast the iterator. What should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103543/how-does-overloading-of-const-and-non-const-functions-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In standard containers, a non-const iterator is implicitly convertible to a const_iterator. The type returned is based solely on the const-ness of the object/reference on which `begin()` was called, which in your case would be `iterator`, there is a conversion that allows the later assignment.

In particular in the 23.2.1 General Container Requirements, table 96, it says that `X::iterator` must be convertible to `X::const_iterator`.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, there are two things : first, the type returned is based on the const-ness on the object itself; second, an iterator can be converted to a const_iterator. How would I do the second thing? There is a line about that in my stl_iterator.h file but I don't understand it...

Comment: @Arthur: The conversion must be implemented in either `iterator` or `const_iterator`, and it absolutely depends on what the objects are. In most cases both iterators hold a *cursor* into the container and just offer slightly different operations (the return types of `operator*` and `operator->` differ). If that is the case, you just need to provide a constructor in `const_iterator` that takes a `iterator` and copies the internal *cursor*.

Answer (score 3):

list knows which kind of iterator to return because there are two begin methods defined, one for when the list is const, and one for when it isn't. The declarations might look something like this:

```
template<class T>
class list {
public:
    iterator<T> begin();
    const_iterator<T> begin() const;
}
```

In the following example, the first, non-const iterator would be returned, because the list isn't const:

```
void doSomething(list<int> &myList) {
    iterator<int> i = myList.begin();
    ...
}
```

In the next example, the list is declared as const, so the second version of begin that returns a const_iterator would be used instead:

```
void doSomethingElse(const list<int> &myList) {
    const_iterator<int> i = myList.begin();
    ....
}
```

Of course, an iterator can always be cast to a const_iterator, so you could declare i to be a const_iterator in either example, but if you try to declare i to be an iterator in the second example you'll get an error since a const_iterator can not be implicitly cast as an iterator.

Comment: Ah, had "forgotten" that C++ can overload by `const`ness of methods... magic!