# Why is inheritance of a const/non-const function overload ambiguous?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, multiple-inheritance

I was trying to create two classes, the first with a non-const implementation of the functions, the second with a const implementation. Here is a small example:

```
class Base {
protected:
  int some;
};

class A : public virtual Base {
  const int& get() const {
    return some;
  }
};

class B : public virtual Base {
  int& get() {
    return some;
  }
};

class C : public A, B {};

C test;
test.get(); // ambiguous
```

The call to the `get` function is ambiguous. No matter that the const version needs to match more requirements. (Calling `get` on const `C` is ambiguous as well, but there is one possible function to call.)
Is there a reason for such behaviour in the standard? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103543/how-does-overloading-of-const-and-non-const-functions-work

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ambiguity occurs when compiler tries to figure out to what entity does the name `get` refer to, prior to overload resolution. It can be a name of function from class A or from class B. In order to build a list of overloads complier needs to select just one of the classes to pull functions from. In order to fix it you can bring that name from both of the base classes into derived class (and make them public):

```
class C : public A, public B { public: using A::get; public: using B::get; };
```

Comment: An annoying C++ niggle!

Comment: An important C++ protection: if adding a function to a base class changed the overload set your code could quietly break; with this rule it breaks noisily.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that you don't actually have one unified overload-set, in which the mutable variant would be unambiguously best, but **two distinct** overload-sets, in `A` and `B`, and the compiler *will not* automatically merge them.

Put

```
using A::get;
using B::get;
```

in `C` to merge the overload-sets and thus resolve the ambiguity.