# Cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Bullet' to 'Bullet &'

Tags: c++, list, iterator, const-iterator

I am trying to use a list for my bullets.
Whenever I run my update bullet code it gives me this error:

Error 1 error C2662: 'Bullet::detectCollision' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Bullet' to 'Bullet &'

my list:

```
std::list<Bullet> bullet_list;
```

my update code:

```
std::list<Bullet>::const_iterator cIter;
    for ( cIter = bullet_list.begin( ); cIter != bullet_list.end( ); cIter++ )
    {
        if((*cIter).detectCollision(monster.position,monster.getHeight(),monster.getWidth()))
        {
//Do stuff here
        }
        if ((*cIter).detectCollision(boss.getPosition(),boss.getHeight(),boss.getWidth()))
        {
//Do stuff here
        }
    }
```

my detect collision code:

```
bool Bullet::detectCollision(Vector objTwo,int heightT,int widthT)
{
if(position.getVectorX() >= objTwo.getVectorX() - (widthT/2) && position.getVectorX() <= objTwo.getVectorX() + (widthT/2)
    && position.getVectorY() >= objTwo.getVectorY() - (widthT/2)&& position.getVectorY() <= objTwo.getVectorY() + (heightT/2) && alive)
{
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: have you tried define the functions you use as const? You use a const iterator.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309581/const-and-nonconst-stl-iterators, if you change something with your iterator by calling the member function maybe it causes the problem, try just "cout <<" it, or try with a non const iterator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare `detectCollision` as `const`.

```
bool Bullet::detectCollision(Vector objTwo,int heightT,int widthT) const
```

When you don't, it's trying to do a conversion so it can call a non-const function on a const reference but it's not allowed.

Comment: Thank you. Took some work to fix the errors adding const caused but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You are using const_iterator but trying to access a non-const member function. Either use iterator instead of the const_iterator or declare the function as const if it can be a const member function.

Answer (score 1):

A `const_iter` does not allow the values it points at to be changed, so when you're calling `detectCollision` you need to promise the compiler you also won't change those values(make the function `const`).