# Why is it showing no operator= for my vector iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

This is the function for computing maximum sum of a subarray

```
int Solution::maxSubArray(const vector<int> &A) {
vector<int>::iterator i;


int max_so_far = *A.begin();
int current_max = *A.begin();


for(i = A.begin(); i != A.end(); ++i)
{   
    current_max = max(*i,*i+current_max);
    max_so_far = max(max_so_far,current_max)
}
return max_so_far;
```

}

This is the error , I'm getting this for C++11 and not in previous versions. Help me solve this

```
solution.cpp: In member function 'int Solution::maxSubArray(const      std::vector<int>&)':
solution.cpp:9:8: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are     'std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*,     std::vector<int> >}' and 'std::vector<int>::const_iterator {aka    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >}')
  for(i = A.begin(); i != A.end(); ++i) 
    ^
solution.cpp:9:8: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
             from solution.h:7,
             from solution.cpp:-3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:708:11: note:    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >&    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >::operator=(const   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >&)
     class __normal_iterator
            ^
  /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:708:11: note:   no known      conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<int>::const_iterator {aka   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >}' to 'const   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >&'
 /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:708:11: note:   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >& __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >::operator=    (__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >&&)
  /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:708:11: note:   no known      conversion for argument 1 f
```

Comment: Aside: `current_max = max(*i,*i+current_max);` is incredibly suspicious, don't you mean `current_sum`? You are summing `A`, and `max_so_far` will only be different if some of the values are negative

Answer (score 11):

You need to use `vector<int>::const_iterator` instead of `vector<int>::iterator`.

If you are working with a compiler that supports C++11 or later version, you can use `auto` type.

```
auto i = A.begin();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a regular iterator to go through const vector.

`vector<int>::iterator i` must be `::const_iterator i`.

See this question [What is the difference between const_iterator and non-const iterator in the C++ STL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309581/const-and-nonconst-stl-iterators)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing the vector as a *const*, a normal *iterator* won't do the job. 
Instead you need a *const_iterator* for a *const vector*.

```
int Solution::maxSubArray(const vector<int> &A) {
vector<int>::const_iterator i;
for(i = A.begin(); i != A.end(); ++i)
{   
 ....
}
```

That should fix it for you!

Answer (score 0):

The iterator needs to be a `const_iterator` as the parameter is `const vector<int>`

---

Change the line

```
vector<int>::iterator i;
```

to

```
vector<int>::const_iterator i;
```

---

Or use `auto` to get the type