# understanding the type of dereference - const_iterator

Tags: c++, types, dereference, const-iterator

I have this declaration:

```
list<string*>::const_iterator iter;
```

I am trying to understand whether the type of `*iter` is: `string*` , `const string*` or something else.

I read that `cost_iterator` returns reference.
On the one hand the list contains `string*` and the iterator points to those.
on the other hand it is `const_iterator` so the value it points to should be `const` and it acts as if the data in the list is `const`? despite it is not really?
not sure what am I missing and what is the right answer.

Comment: Type should be `string const *` - `constant pointer to non const data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general answer is `const T &`, which I prefer to write `T const &` because it composes correctly in the next paragraph.

For `T=string*`, we get `string * const &`, or a *reference to a constant pointer to a string*.

This means you can't mutate the list element (via a const_iterator) by pointing it to a different string, but you *can* indirectly mutate the list by altering the string to which it points.

You can read the definitions of [`std::list<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), but it isn't as clear as it could be about the iterator behaviour - it works out like so:

- `std::list<T>::value_type` is the same as `T`

  - so `std::list<string*>::value_type` is `string*`.
- `std::list<T>::const_iterator` models a `const` [LegacyBidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator)
- LegacyBidirectionalIterator is a [LegacyForwardIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) which must satisfy [LegacyInputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator)
- LegacyInputIterator must support the expression `*i` returning type `reference`
- and finally, from the LegacyForwardIterator we rather skipped over

  > - The type std::iterator_traits::reference must be exactly
  >
  >   ...
  >     const T& otherwise (It is constant),
  >
  > (where T is the type denoted by std::iterator_traits::value_type)

  which is how we get from the type named `reference` to the `const T &` we started with.

Comment: Well put.  My Stroustrup 4ed says  "  `const_iterator` Behaves like a `const value_type` "

Answer (score 5):

`std::list<T>::const_iterator::operator*` returns a `const T&`.  Since your list stores a `string*` that means you'll get a reference to a `string * const` as the `const` applies to `T`, not to what `T` points to if it is a pointer.

Comment: That question looked familiar:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309581/what-is-the-difference-between-const-iterator-and-non-const-iterator-in-the-c