# How could I iterator a vector as a member of class while the corresponding objects pass as a const

Tags: c++

I have a simple class with only one member which is a vector, just like this:

```
class MyClass{
private:
    vector<double> vector_member;
public:
    method_1();
    method_2();
    ....
};
```

And when I trying to overload an operator such as +=, which should add each element in the vectors in two objects and return a vector as a sum of them.
My approach so far is:

```
MyClass& MyClass :: operator+=(const MyClass& p){
    size_t n = max(this->vector_member.size(),p.vector_member.size());
    MyClass temp;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        temp.vector_member.push_back(0);
    }
    vector<double>::iterator it_1 = this->vector_member.begin();
    vector<const double>::iterator it_2 = p.vector_member.begin();
    vector<double>::iterator it_3 = temp.vector_member.begin();

    for (; it_1 != this->vector_member.end(); ++it_1, ++it_3){
        *it_3 += *it_1;
    }

    it_3 = temp.vector_member.begin();

    for (; it_2 != p.vector_member.end(); ++it_2, ++it_3){
        *it_3 += *it_2;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

The reason that I set up a temp vector is, I need a vector with the max size of those two vectors to avoid Segmentation fault.

My problem is at each time when I try to do `vector<const double>::iterator it_2 = p.vector_member.begin();` or `it_2 != p.vector_member.end()`.

The vs code seems not happy with this. It says cannot convert between `"__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const double *, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>>"`  and `"__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const double *, std::vector<const double, std::allocator<const double>>>"`

I don't know how to fix this, and also is there any smart way to do this? I think my code is so broken. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between const\_iterator and non-const iterator in the C++ STL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309581/what-is-the-difference-between-const-iterator-and-non-const-iterator-in-the-c)

Comment: You need a const iterator for a `const` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input `MyClass p` object is `const`, so its `vector<double>` is also `const`, and as such you need to use `vector<double>::const_iterator` to iterate its elements, not `vector<const double>::iterator`.  That is why you are getting the compiler error.

But, even fixing that, your code is still wrong.  `operator+=` is supposed to *modify* `this` and then return `*this`.  But you are not doing that.  You are creating a whole new `MyClass` object and returning a (dangling) reference to that instead.  Your `operator+=` is acting more like how `operator+` should act (see [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/)).

Try this instead:

```cpp
MyClass& MyClass :: operator+=(const MyClass& p){
    size_t n = p.vector_member.size();
    if (n > this->vector_member.size())
        this->vector_member.resize(n);

    vector<double>::iterator it_1 = this->vector_member.begin();
    vector<double>::const_iterator it_2 = p.vector_member.begin();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        *it_1++ += *it_2++;
    }

    /* alternatively:

    size_t n = std::max(this->vector_member.size(), p.vector_member.size());
    std::vector<double> temp(n, 0.0);

    vector<double>::iterator it_1 = this->vector_member.begin();
    vector<double>::const_iterator it_2 = p.vector_member.begin();
    vector<double>::iterator it_3 = it_3 = temp.begin();

    while (it_1 != this->vector_member.end()){
        *it_3++ += *it_1++;
    }

    it_3 = temp.begin(); 
    while (it_2 != p.vector_member.end()){
        *it_3++ += *it_2++;
    }

    this->vector_member = std::move(temp);
    */

    return *this;
}

MyClass operator+(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs){
    MyClass temp(lhs);
    temp += rhs;
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
vector<const double>::iterator it_2 = p.vector_member.begin();
```

This should be:

```
vector<double>::const_iterator it_2 = p.vector_member.begin();
```

Your vector is always a vector of `double` values. It is ***the vector itself*** that's constant here. It does make the contents of the vector effectively `const`, but they are still `double`s, "by the book".

Also, in the post C++11 world, this can be simply:

```
auto it_2 = p.vector_member.begin();
```

And let the chips fall where they may...

P.S. The operator you implemented is fundamentally broken for a reason unrelated to your compilation error: it's returning a reference to a temporary object. You really implemented an `operator+`, if you return not a reference but the `temp` value itself, and not a reference to it. An `operator+=` is expected to ***modify itself***, rather than create a new object and return it. In any case, there's appears to be a much simpler and shorter way to accomplish a logically equivalent `operator+`: copy-construct your `temp` from `*this`, resize its vector to the same `max()` value (which will zero-initialize any new values automatically), then simply add the other vector's values to the copy's vector. Should be about half as much code.